# Mathematical symbols issue in displaying

Tags: fonts

I'm having a strange issue on my android device. Oh, this is mathematical:

On my android device, using Brave, Opera, or DDG browsers I cannot see many symbols in mathematical pages on wiki. The symbols do not show up or are showing up as white. It seems to be just a few symbols but it can make it very difficult to follow what is going on. The symbol p usually is missing(but q show sup).

e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)

All the p's and V's are missing(but they take up space).

I have no idea what is going on and I don't know where to look for to ask. Is it a wiki problem? MathJax? These browsers? My device? This is making it very painful to use the device to read wikipedia. I haven't seen it on other sites but I don't go to many other sites for math.

Any ideas?

Comment: A screen shot would be good that demonstrates the problem. And also please add the Android version and the device model you use.

Comment: Unlike the usual suspect of "missing font", this looks like an SVG rendering issue on browsers since Wikipedia uses SVG images for Maths symbols, or those images are blocked by the network. Could you mention the device model and the Android version? Also, are those images shown using different Wi-Fi/mobile data?

Comment: @AndrewT. I thought it might be related to SVG. I don't have mobile data. Android 6 Lenovo. Although I don't know why it would matter.  Do you have any idea what I can do to figure it out? Is SVG rendering external to the browsers? Would there be a possible browser I could try that could help narrow down the possibilities?